# como tirar uma tag

Tags: javascript, html5

eu tenho as tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body onload="">
        <script src="data/js/main/engine.js"></script>
        <script src="data/js/main/canvas.js"></script>
        <script src="data/js/main/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

e tenho um codigo pra adicinar novos scripts

```
function Script(src=""){
    this.script=document.createElement("script")
    this.load=function(){
        this.script.src=src;
        document.body.appendChild(this.script);
    }
    this.deload=function(){
        this.script.src=null;
        document.body.removeChild(this.script);
    }
}
```

so que a parte de remover o script não funciona como eu posso remover o script das tags body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a lógica de chamar o elemento pai com **.parentNode** e aí sim utilizar o **.removeChild()** no elemento que deseja remover.

```js
this.script.parentNode.removeChild(this.script);
```

Comment: valeu tu me ajudou muito